# ASP.NET custom control, can I taking data from a <template> and convert it to a string?

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I'm trying to have an asp.net custom control with a field like:

```
<ErrorTemplate>
<h1>Error</h1>
<p>Blue wizard shot the food</p>
</ErrorTemplate>
```

What I want to end up with is:

`<h1>Error</h1><p>Blue wizard shot the food</p>` in a string in my codebehind.

At the moment, the process I use to get this data out of the template is:

First this gets instantiated into a placeholder by my code:

```
ErrorTemplate.InstantiateIn(errorPHolder);
```

which is an asp.net placeholder control - it has to be instantiated into something which can support controls.

What I then want to do is add this to my page using JQuery and a variable, like this:

```
string script = "var Errortemplate = " + errorPHolder.ToString() + ";";
scriptmanager.register(script); // pseudocode
```

so the result would be, on my page:

```
var Errortemplate = '<h1>Error</h1><p>Blue wizard shot the food</p>';
```

Then I can use JQuery to do `someDiv.html(Errortemplate);`

Finally resulting in whatever they put in `<ErrorTemplate>` appearing on the page

Because I'm using JQuery it might be possible to do this a different way, such as adding the placeholder to the page into a hidden div and using JQuery to copy the values out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to render your control?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb))
{
    using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw))
    {
        errorPHolder.RenderControl(hw);
    }
}

// its HTML string representation of errorPHolder
string html = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: This worked superbly, thanks! Didn't know about `HtmlTextWriter` until now =)